# How to Get Only Day Name or Number in a Week in JavaScript Date()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following code snippets to get the First and last Day of month which working fine but what I need is getting only the Name string like "Fri", "Wed", "Sun" and the code is returning a long Date format as:

> Fri Oct 31 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

```
var today = new Date();
var lastOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth()+1, 0);

var today = new Date();
var firstOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(), 1);
```

Can you please let me know how I can get ONLY the Name or Number of the day in a week  (using `getDay()`) of the First day?

Comment: For date related stuff in JavaScript, your life will probably be easier using something like `moment.js`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use haven't use getDay

```
today.getDay();
```

first of month

```
 firstOfMonth.getDay();
```

last of month

```
 lastOfMonth.getDay();
```

or if u want to get dayname use

```
var days = ['Sun','Mon','Tues','Wed','Thrus','Fri','Sat'];
//First of month
days[firstOfMonth.getDay()];
//last of month
days[lastOfMonth.getDay()];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define arrays

```
var Months = ['Jan','Feb'....];
var Days = ['Sun','Mon','Tues','Wednes','Thurs','Fri','Sat'];

var firstOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(),Months[today.getMonth()], 1);

var Day = Days[today.getDay()];
```

Comment: Hi Fatima, Thanks for reply this is working but I didnt get why uou used the Months[]?

Answer (score 1):

Use

`lastOfMonth.getDay()`

to get the day number.

You can use an array like

```
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";
```

to get the written day with

```
var writtenDay = weekday[lastOfMonth.getDay()];
```

Answer (score 0):

The getDay() function in JavaScript returns a number from 0-6 depending on the day of the week, so maybe just make an array like:

`weekDay = [Sun Mon Tue Wed Thur Fri Sat]`

And then `weekDay[your_date_object.getDay()]` would do the trick. You can wrap it all in a function for better usability.

Answer (score 0):

```
var days = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"];
alert(days[today.getDay() - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is **exactly** the week of day how it appears in the `Date` format you can:

```
firstOfMonth.toString().split(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try code [here](http://jsbin.com/quseti/2/). It's very simple

```
lastOfMonth.toString().split(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Reusable and simpler approach with two example

1. with callback function for DOM, we can call any function.
2. simple usage just call `getDayNameByDate('YYYY-MM-DD')` or `getDayNameByDate('MM-DD-YYYY')`

```js
const getDayNameByDate = (date , callback ) => {
  const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" ];
  const dayIndex = new Date( date ).getDay()
  const res = days[dayIndex]; 
  if(callback) { callback(res) }
  return res
}


/* optional function */
const showDom = async ( res ) => {
  const output = await document.getElementById('output');
  output.innerHTML = res
}



console.log(
 'Today day is: ', getDayNameByDate( new Date() )
)
```

```html
<p>Change date and see result</p>
<input placeholder='YYYY-MM-DD or MM-DD-YYYY' onkeyup="getDayNameByDate(this.value, showDom) " />
<p>This day is: <b id="output">N/A</b></p>
```